# How to refine a covering of the Cantor set by intervals to a covering by disjoint segments?

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set

Let $C$ be the [Cantor Middle Third Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) in $[0,1],$

> **Question** Suppose that $\{O_1,O_2,...,O_n \}$ is a finite covering for $C,$ where each $O_i$ is an open interval for all $1\leq i \leq n.$
>
> By rearrangement, we can assume that left endpoints of $O_i$ are in ascending order.
>
> For any
> $1\leq i \leq n,$ does there exist $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ such that $$[\alpha_i,\beta_i] \subseteq O_i, [\alpha_{i+1},\beta_{i+1}]\subseteq O_{i+1}, \alpha_i<\beta_i<\alpha_{i+1}<\beta_{i+1}, \bigcup_{I=1}^n [\alpha_i,\beta_i] \supseteq C$$
> and $\alpha_i,\beta_i = \frac{m_i}{3^{n_i}}$ for some $m_i,n_i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m_i$ is not divisible by $3?$

I am trying to construct $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ for $\{ O_1,O_2,O_3 \}.$

Let $O_1 = (c_1,d_1), O_2 = (c_2,d_2)$ and $O_3 = (c_3,d_3)$ be such that $c_1<c_2<c_3.$
Clearly $c_1<0.$
So we can choose $\alpha_1 = \frac{m_1}{3^{n_1}}$ for large enough $n_1$ so that $c_1<\alpha_1<0.$

Now, problem lies in getting $\beta_1.$
**Clearly we need $\beta_1$ and $\alpha_2$ such that there is no element $x$ in Cantor set that lies between $\beta_1$ and $\alpha_2.$**
Otherwise, $C$ may not be contained in the union of $[\alpha_i,\beta_i].$
But I have no idea how to choose such $\beta_1.$

I think this can be done as $C$ is nowhere dense, that is, for every interval $I,$ there is a subinterval $J\subseteq I$ such that $J\cap C = \emptyset.$

Comment: Two hints. 1. Does $O_i\cap C$ necessarily have a smallest element? A largest element? 2. What are the endpoints of the removed intervals like? Answer these and figure out how to use the answers to solve your original problem.

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen: No, $O_i \cap C$ may not have the smallest and largest element. Endpoints of removed intervals have non-terminating ternary decimal. For example, base $3$ form of $\frac{1}{3}$ is $0.01111....$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ is an endpoint of removed interval.

Comment: 1. Can you give an example? 2. OK, but are they fractions? If yes, what kind?

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen 1. Let $O_i = (-1,\frac{1}{3}).$ Then $O_i \cap C$ does not have the largest element, say $y.$ If it does, then $y$ is in an open set and by definition, it is in an open interval. This contradicts with $y$ being an element of $C.$ By symmetry, $O_i\cap C$ does not have the smallest element.  2. They are fractions of the form $\frac{m}{3^n}$ for some integer $m$ and $n.$

Comment: 1. Let $O_1=(-1,1/3)$. What is $O_2$? 2. Yes.

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen: 1. $O_2 = (\frac{1}{4}, \frac{2}{3})$? I am not sure what you asking. $O_2$ can be any set with left endpoint bigger than $0,$ right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71961/discussion-between-taneli-huuskonen-and-idonknow).

Comment: Sorry, I thought the intervals $O_i$ were supposed to be mutually disjoint to avoid a silly counterexample like $O_1=(-1,2),O_2=(0,1)$. My first hint makes sense only then. My bad. Anyway, under suitable conditions you can shorten the intervals to make them mutually disjoint, and a solution for the shorter ones will also work for the original ones.

Comment: @Idonknow I’m writing a proof but we need to adjust the question because otherwise we have a simple counterexample with $n=2$, $O_1=(-1,2)$ and $O_2=(\frac 13,\frac 23)$. Indeed, we need to have $\alpha_1\le 0$ and $\beta_1\ge 1$, so $[\alpha_2,\beta_2]\subset O_2\subset [\alpha_1,\beta_1]$. I see two ways to fix this issue. First of them, which I assume for the proof, is to demand that only  $[\alpha_1,\beta_1]\cap C\subset O_i$.

Comment: The second is to assume that for each $j\ge 1$ the right endpoint of $O_j$ is bigger than the right endpoint of $O_{j-1}$ and I think that my proof can be adapted for this case too. Which fix do you prefer?

Comment: @AlexRavsky: I thought in my question is stated that right endpoint of $O_j$ must be greater than right endpoint $O_{j-1},$ particularly, $\beta_{j}\geq \beta_{j-1}?$

Comment: @AlexRavsky: I prefer second modification.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Hi.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found a gap in my (inductive) proof, but I'll try to find an other proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $\mathcal O=\{O_1,O_2,...,O_n \}$ and $O=\bigcup\mathcal O$. Since $\{C_m\}$ (see the Wikipedia reference) is a family of compact sets and $C=\bigcap C_m\subset O$, there exists $C_m\subset O$ (this simple fact even can be referenced as a corollary of  Šura-Bura Lemma). Pick $k\ge m$ such that $1/3^{k}$ is smaller than [Lebesgue number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma) of the covering $\mathcal O$ of $C_m$.
For any segment $S$ constituting $C_k$ let $i(S)$ be the smallest $i$ such that $S\subset O_i$. For each $i$ put $C(i)=\bigcup\{S:i(S)=i\}$, and if $C(i)\ne\varnothing$ put $\alpha_i=\min C(i)$, and $\beta_i=\max C(i)$. The choice of $k$ implies that $C_k\subset\bigcup C(i)$, the convexity of $O’s$ implies that $[\alpha_i,\beta_i]\subset O_i$ for each $i$, also the construction implies that $\beta_i<\alpha_{j}$ for each $i<j$. At last, it is easy to check that we can consecutively insert small segments $[\alpha_j,\beta_j]\subset O_j$ with ternary rational endpoints (necessarily disjoint with $C_k$) for these $j$ with empty $C_j$ before already constructed $[\alpha_i,\beta_i]$ and after the last $[\alpha_i,\beta_i]$ (for instance, in $n=7$, $C(2)$, $C(3)$, and $C(7)$ are empty then we insert $[\alpha_3,\beta_3]$ before $[\alpha_4,\beta_4]$, then $[\alpha_2,\beta_2]$ before $[\alpha_3,\beta_3]$, and then $[\alpha_7,\beta_7]$ after $[\alpha_4,\beta_4]$). Finally, we have $C\subset C_k\subset\bigcup[\alpha_i,\beta_i]\subset O$.

Comment: By segment $S,$ do you refer to closed intervals in $C_m$ for some natural number $m?$ For example, in $C_1 = [0,\frac{1}{3}] \cup [\frac{2}{3},1],$ the two closed intervals are two segments?

Comment: @Idonknow Right.

Comment: I do not undestand your example when $n=7.$ Why would $C(2), C(3)$ and $C(7)$ be empty?

Comment: @Idonknow They are empty by the assumption. This example is given only to illustrate the insertion order for a case when some $C(i)$ are empty.